# Where do you configure the Starcraft 2 alerts location on the screen?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've seen screencasts from both Artosis and Day[9] where the alerts like "upgrade completed" show up in the chat area of the screen (bottom middle) instead of on the left side. Is this a 3rd party tool or UI mod, or is there a configuration setting I don't see?

Comment: +1, maybe with this the new mule/chronoboost/larvae alerts introduced in 1.3 will come to any good use, now you just never notice them...

Comment: Yeah that is exactly why I want to find out, I want to get chronoboost alerts in a place where I will actually notice them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an alert pops on the left side of your screen (below the menu), you just have to hit the space bar and the main screen will be automatically centered on the structure that completed the upgrade / unit. A message corresponding to the event is displayed on the screen (the message you are asking about).

Comment: you just edited the fundamental meaning of the question to something trivial, and then answered that trivial question. The OP is asking how you can configure the location on the screen of the alerts.

Comment: @tenfour The question is based on the wrong assumption that the alerts on the "chat area" replace the alerts on the left side of the screen, which they don't. Pressing the spacebar just pops out the alerts on the left, center the view on the alert source and display a message.

Comment: For the record I didn't downvote; I agree with you but I think your comment would have been a better answer to the question than your real answer + edit to original question. Cheers :)